# How to get certificate type from SSL Certificate of a domain?

Tags: linux, openssl, certificates

Is there any way to get Certificate Type (*EV/OV/DV*) from the certificate?

I tried the following command and get entire certificate at output, but can't find Certificate Type from it.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -issuer
```

Is there any way to get certificate type?

Comment: There is no standard way to obtain this information:
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35076/how-does-an-end-user-differentiate-between-ov-and-dv-certificates